# How to execute a portion of code for the first request hitting the webserver in Application_BeginRequest?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading

I want to log the first request hitting my server, so I have wrote that portion of code in my Global.asax.cs

```
private bool _startupHasBeenLogged = false;
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!_startupHasBeenLogged)
    {
        DoLog();
        _startupHasBeenLogged = true;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I get the log for the first 5 or 6 requests. I guess the server receive multiple request at once, and so DoLog is hitting multiple times before the boolean becomes true.

I have tried using Interlocked:

```
int running = 0;
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref running, 1, 0) != 0) return;
    if (!_startupHasBeenLogged)
    {
        _startupHasBeenLogged = true;
        DoLog();
    }
    Interlocked.Exchange(ref running, 0);
}
```

And Monitor.TryEnter:

```
private static readonly object _lock = new object();
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Monitor.TryEnter(_lock))
    {
        try
        {
            if (!_startupHasBeenLogged)
            {
                _startupHasBeenLogged = true;
                DoLog();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(_lock);
        }
    }
}
```

But everytime, the log is firing 5 or 6 times.

So how do I run a code only one time for the very first Request in a webserver?

**Edit Solution :**

The details I missed was that [the Application is instanciated multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31837463/128662), so _startupHasBeenLogged had multiple instances. The lock works fine. Just declare a static bool

```
private static bool _startupHasBeenLogged = false;
```

Comment: Why not use Application_Start event instead?

Comment: apply the above logic on void Session_Start() event ?

Comment: I want to log a Request, and Request object are not available on Application or Session start

Comment: Are you using IIS? If so, is it possible that you have multiple worker processes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ASP.NET instantiates your `HttpApplication` derived class multiple times](https://lowleveldesign.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/global-asax-in-asp-net/). I think it's an object pool. I find this design appalling. It has no practical use.

Don't put state in the application object. Create a separate class that has static variables. They are global per AppDomain. ASP.NET can't mess with them.

Of course, there can be situations where multiple app domains are running at the same time but that's rare. it happens when recycling a pool for example.

Comment: Good info on the HttpApplication pool; I never knew that.

Comment: @MarkBrackett nobody does, and it is asinine.

Answer (score 0):

There is the following overrides on controller.

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)


protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
```

I have used this in a baseController class before.